# Getting a input value in django view after inserting html by AJAX

Tags: javascript, python, html, django, ajax

In my html, i insert a code by ajax request like:

```
if (document.getElementById("div3").className == "active"){
            for (var [name, value] of Object.entries(institutionsByName)){
                  document.getElementById("institution-checkbox").innerHTML +=
                  '<label name="organization_label">' +
                  '<input type="checkbox" name="organization" value="' + value + '" id="institution-key"/>' +
                  '<span class="checkbox radio"></span>' + 
                  '<span class="description">' + 
                    '<div class="title">'+ name + '</div>' +
                    '<div class="subtitle">' + 
                    '</div>' +
                  '</span>' + 
                '</label>'
          }    
        }
```

Then i try to get a 'organization' value by django view like:

```
institutions1 = request.POST.get('institution-key')
```

However it returns None,
How can i get the id of my institution/organization in a correct way in my django view?

In html code, one of them looks like:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="organization" value="9" id="institution-key">
```

Comment: Can you try this request.POST['organization']

Comment: It also returns 'None'

Answer (score 0):

Few things:

1. If you are inserting multiple items, don't use the same ID, the IDs should be unique within a HTML document (this does not produce any errors, but use classes instead)
2. The form submitted will use the name of the form elements, in this case `organization` would be the one you should look for, not `institution-key`
3. If you have the scope to do so, perhaps look in to a JS library that will make manipulating HTML a lot easier.

Comment: request.POST.get('organization') also returns None

Comment: Have you inspected `request.POST` to see if it contains any other values? Does the JS correctly submit the form? Is your input element correctly placed within a form element?

Comment: Actually i've done some kind of trick (in my opinion) - i've created another input with class 'hidden' and i've put into this input the checked checkbox by javascript, then my django view takes value from that input without problem.